# How do I use google cloud storage as a bucket to store user/client images in a MERN Stack app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm working on a pretty vanilla boilerplate blog-style application using mongoDB, express, react and node. It allows for user registration, authentication, for authorized users to CRUD posts, make comments, and reply to comments (so far).

I have a well defined schema (using mongoose) and the `User` model has an `avatar` field which is supposed to be the URI for the profile picture for that user. That is what I'm now stuck at: integrating image hosting on Google Cloud Storage for the profile picture that the user uploads and then fetching the URL and saving it to `user.avatar`.

I've tried looking this up extensively but I really can't find a reliable solution to this. I should probably mention that this is the first time I'm working with file uploads (I'm a student, though this isn't a homework question).

Honestly, any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Edit: I have tried going through the docs for Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to make this work? I am looking for exactly the same and I know how to do it if images were fully public. However, I want the user avatar to be private and only accessible by the user. Any hint would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi there! I don't know if this helps but I ended up going with AWS S3 Storage instead, it was much easier to set up tbh.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage has some good information, in `Upload to Cloud Storage` section.

```
function sendUploadToGCS (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.file) {
    return next();
  }

  const gcsname = Date.now() + req.file.originalname;
  const file = bucket.file(gcsname);

  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    resumable: false
  });

  stream.on('error', (err) => {
    req.file.cloudStorageError = err;
    next(err);
  });

  stream.on('finish', () => {
    req.file.cloudStorageObject = gcsname;
    file.makePublic().then(() => {
      req.file.cloudStoragePublicUrl = getPublicUrl(gcsname); // this will be the URL you will use in your web pages
      next();
    });
  });

  stream.end(req.file.buffer);
}
```

Example also uses [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) which is a middleware for Express, for handling file uploads

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I hadn't even noticed that page, I'll try it out right away and see how it goes.

Comment: Your response assumes images will be public so everyone can see them. Is there a way to make it only visible to the user uploading the image? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Depending where you want the processing to happen, either in the frontend with React or in the backend with Express, you can use the Google Cloud Client library to upload the files to GCS and then either use [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) or the Link URL that you can find inside the Object details in GCS and place it inside a `<img src=... />` tag.

For instance, with the help of this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs) you can upload files like such:

/utilities/utils.js

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();

export const uploadObject = async (bucketName, fileName) => {
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename);
}
```

/routes/gcs.js

```
[...]
const { uploadObject } = require('../utilities/utils');

router.post('/api/uploadAvatar', async (req, res) => {
  await uploadObject(req.body.bucketName, req.body.fileName);
});
```

This example is specific to a case where you would do these kind of processes in the backend, but the concepts should apply the same if you decide to do it in the frontend.

For starters, I would recommend deciding early how you want to divide your React.js code and Express.js code. Do you want to employ a [microservices-like architecture](https://microservices.io/patterns/microservices.html) and have React call REST endpoints in the backend (server-side processing) for most tasks and keep client-side processing to a minimum? Or do you simply want to use your backend for communicating with mongodb and perform most processes in React? There are plenty of viable architectures out there and I invite you to lay out a meticulous plan beforehand!

Comment: I am indeed planning on keeping the Client-side load to a minimum so this would have to be done on the server. I'll try that though, thanks.

Comment: Great, let me know how it went.

Comment: So I tried basically everything I could find in their docs only to repeatedly end up with the following error: 

```Error: The project to be billed is associated with an absent billing account```

This is when I'm certain that the project is associated with a very much present billing account. 

*sigh*

I'm just gonna try using AWS S3 instead. It's just a bit disappointing because I really wanted to use GCP.

Comment: Have you checked if the bucket you specified exists? That error often pops up when specifying a non-existing bucket, click the (Open The Cloud Storage Browser) blue button and check [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets) or if you have ran out of [Cloud Storage Always Free usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#cloud-storage-always-free) which I don't think is the case here since you just started out. In any case, if you want to pursue resolving this issue further, I'm more than willing to help.

Comment: That's a bizarre error description for an invalid bucket name. But yeah, no I did double check that, I had definitely specified the correct bucket. I'll try again tomorrow as I've been at uni all day today, but seriously, thanks a ton for helping me out.

Comment: No worries, also check if you have a billing account opened and linked to your project. When the billing account is closed, you have a limited set of resources and will then face an error if you use paid resources. Know that even in the event of free trial, you will still have to keep the billing account open. I also suggest you to create an entry in [Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product) and have a direct communication with an engineer.

Comment: You can also create a [Private Cloud Storage issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491168) using this link. Only Googlers and people CC'd in the bug can see it. Once the issue has been created, you can post the link in here so that I can help you in much greater detail.

Comment: I did definitely have an open billing account and it was linked to my project. To be honest, I'm pretty sure I was doing something wrong as the file upload and storage is working with AWS (though that took a few hours as well). I will definitely give GCP another shot once I'm done with this project as the deadline is closer than I'd like. Thanks for all your help though, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Happy to help, best of luck in your future endeavors!